# Please explain how minor 6/9 chords are used in a tune

Tags: theory

What do you use the minor 6/9 chords for?  The chord sounds like it is for ending a song. Could you show how these chords, Gm76/9 and Em76/9, are used in a tune?

Comment: Don't think I've ever played a 'm76/9' chord.

Comment: Can you list the notes you think are in this chord? "76/9" ... looks like a misunderstanding.

Comment: I had the same question `Gm76/9` I guess would be `G Bb D F A E`, and now that I've written it out, it's like a thirteenth chord with a minor third. An odd chord.

Comment: Yeah, so it's like a dorian scale with only 11 step omitted. Very "modal" sound. It also has two semitones (9–b3 and 6–b7) which opens interesting voicing possibilities.

Comment: I have never seen Gm76/9. In the major chord, G6/9 often implies the major 7, and you play 3 6 7 9 with the root in the bass. Likewise Gm6/9 can imply the flat 7, and you would play b3 6 b7 9, with the root in the bass. Sounds nice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a 6/9 chord, minor or major, is often used as a decorated tonic. (Not a m7(6/9) though.  I'm assuming the '7' was a slip of the finger.)    It can voice-lead well from an extended dominant chord (first example)  Or, like most chords, it can plane up and down effectively (second example).

Note how I've tried to maintain harmonic density.  When using 'dirty' chords, it's good to maintain the same amount of dirt in each chord.   A plain triad or seventh chord would sound wrong in such company.  Also, pay attention to voice leading. (I've made no attempt to write something that 'fits the fingers' on either piano or guitar.)

[image]

Comment: I too wondered about the seventh. I thought either the sixth or the seventh, but not both.

Comment: Is there a flat missing from the `G` in `Ebm`?

Comment: Indeed.  Well spotted.   Sorted.